# Error while calling secured web service in C#

Tags: wcf, web-services, c#-3.0

I have to connect to secured webservice, I am passing in the credentials while calling the service
But I am getting following error message while calling service

> "An error was discovered processing
>   the < wsse:Security > header"

I am using basicHttpBinding with security mode set to "Transport"

The endpoint address points to secured site URL

I am not sure why I am getting this error message, Am i missing something?

Comment: While not an answer, here's someone getting the very same error message, with some discussion/solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/9b4d8f5c-bdb6-45f0-be5e-e014cccab831

Comment: Are you using NetworkCredential ?

Comment: transport ClientCredentialType is set to "None"

Answer (score 0):

You're using basicHttpBinding, and passing credentials, so I believe you must use something to the effect of:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="myBinding">
     <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
     <transport />
     <message clientCredentialType="Username" />
     </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

This will allow messages to flow via SSL (secure **transport**) with plain credentials.